# Do $Y$ bosons gain a little bit of mass from Higgs of $\bf 5$ rep in $SU(5)$ GUT theory?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

I know that when the Higgs in the **24** rep takes a v.e.v. of this form $$v_{24}\,\mathrm{diag}\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{15}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{15}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{15}} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{15}} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{15}}\\
\end{pmatrix},$$
$SU(5)$ breaks to $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ group, with $X$ and $Y$ bosons getting masses around $10^{15} GeV$. But I noticed that when Higgs in **5** rep gets it's v.e.v. of this form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\frac{v_5}{\sqrt2}\\
\end{pmatrix},$$ which besides coupling to $W^{\pm}$ and $Z$ bosons, also couples to $Y$ bosons since their summed generators form this matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1+i & 1+i & 1+i & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

A **5** Higgs v.e.v. is much much smaller than **24** Higgs, but anyway how much mass does it give them?

Comment: It should even get a small mass contribution from the spontaneous *chiral* symmetry breaking of QCD, at the pion mass scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be schematic and cavalier with normalizations and factors... You can do this right in your peculiar conventions.

I'll call the v.e.v., of the **24** Higgs *v*, following the obligatory sourcebook of the [BEGN paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(78)90214-6), and that of the **5** just $v_0$. They differ by 13 orders of magnitude, of course. For energies in these 13 orders of magnitude in between GUT breaking and EW breaking, only *v* is operative to give mass $5gv/2\sqrt{2}$ to the *Y*s, but *then* there is the extra term of the covariant completion in the kinetic term of the **5**, which is the non vanishing term of the 5-5 element of the square of the matrix you wrote with the v.e.v.s of the **5**, so $m^2=g^2v_0^2/8$.

So, *naively* the add-on to the Y mass at super low energies is a correction 26 orders of magnitude smaller than the GUT mass, $gv \sqrt{ (1+v^2_0/v^2 ) /8 }$; you can expand the square root.  Most people call this *insignificant*, given the extreme speculative nature of the issue.

Nevertheless, this is for fixed *v* and $v_0$, which, as discussed in the BEGN paper, does not obtain, and hinges on the coupling of the *5* to the *24* in the combined potential, which results to shifted values, (4.4'), (4.5'), (4.11'). But, I hope I have convinced you, as far as the "academic" shift you are interested in, this amounts to balancing angels on the head of a pin...